# For Each Loop using a second database table model in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, foreach

I have a cshtml view linked to a controller for a model for one table in my database, but I need to do a for each loop that references a second model for a second table. Since setting 2 models at the top of the page is not possible `foreach (var row in model)` wont work.

what I need is something like this

```
@model MVCapp.Models.COOKIE
@using MVCapp.Models;

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Update";
  ;

  foreach (var row in IEnumerable<MVCapp.Models.COOKIE_JARS)
  {
     some code 
  }
}

<h2>Update</h2>
```

Although that is not aloud because I'm using a type like a variable. So what I am asking is if there is a way to set type:`IEnumerable<MVCapp.Models.COOKIE_JARS` to a variable or a second model, Or if there is a completely alternative method to achieve this looping through a second database table that I am trying to attempt.

Comment: Create a viewmodael that has 2 properties that encapsulate your 2 models or make your model a `Tuple<Model1,Model2>`.

Comment: Oh using the Tuple as a model, never thought of that. It's a bit dirty, I like that :).

Comment: Using `Tuple<Model,Model2>` method I get the does not contain public definition for `GetEnumerator` Using `IEnumerable<Tuple<Model1,Model2>>` Does not seem to fix this as well as `Tuple<IEnumerable<Model>,IEnumerable<Model2>`

Comment: I fixed this by changing `Model` to `Model.Item1` in my foreach loop.

Comment: @RyeNyeTheWebSiteGuy Honestly, I wouldn't recommend using that technique, you'll be a lot better off doing a ViewModel. Using the Tuple method is quite dirty, what would happen if you would need info from a third Model?

Comment: I was only simply exploring the method, for future reference I'm not planning on using it for my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a `ViewModel`, a class that will contain the information of both your models.

You view must never made any logic or get information from your database, this is the goal of the Controller.

So, the idea is that your controller will make the queries, and add the data into your `ViewModel` object that will then be sent to the View.

Example :

Your ViewModel:

```
public class CookieEatersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Cookie> Cookies {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Monster> Monsters {get; set;}
}
```

Your View:

```
@model MVCApp.ViewModels.CookieEatersViewModel

<h2>Update</h2>

<p>Use the informations from your ViewModel here</p>
```

Your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CookieEatersViewModel cevm = new CookieEatersViewModel();
    cevm.Cookies = repo.GetCookies();
    cevm.Monsters = repo.GetMonsters();

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: What does the "repo" do, I get an error on it, is there an assembly i need to add to the top of the file for it to work?

Comment: "repo" was just a sample name for what you'd call your `repository` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx.
It's just a sample to say "get your data from whatever source you have".

Comment: Okay I see, I am very new to developing as specially with MVC and C# so I know very little. Thank you for you help.